# Laravel Widgets across multiple pages

Tags: php, laravel

I have a series of Widgets that look like this:

[image]

Each Widget has a button in the top right that either adds or removes the widget depending on where you are in the application, here is the section of code:

```
div class="col-xs-2">
    @if(Route::current()->uri() == 'welcome')

        <form action="{{ action('WidgetController@destroy', $widgetNo ) }}" method="post">
            @csrf @method('delete')
            <button type="submit" class="widget">
                <i class="fa fa-bars "></i>
            </button>
        </form>

    @elseif(Route::current()->uri() == 'widget-library') 

        @foreach($user->widgets as $widget) 
            @if($widget->widget_id == $widgetNo)

                <i class="fa fa-bars "></i>

                @else

                <form action="{{action('WidgetController@store')}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="widget_id" value="{{ $widgetNo }}">

                    <button type="submit" class="widget">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
                    </button>
                </form>

            @endif 
        @endforeach 
    @endif
</div>
```

When in 'Widget Library' the code checks to see which Widgets the user has and either puts a plus or a bar (as I want to stop the user re-adding a widget they already have).

When you only have one Widget it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see this seems to work.

**There are two issues, however.**

- When a user has more than one Widget the foreach loop loops multipe times creating multiple buttons.
- Also, when a user has no Widgets the icons are not displayed because they're generated within a foreach loop.

The widgets themselves are just HTML so to add a unique ID I have done the following inside my Widget Library view.

```
@include('widgets.quick-search-full-width', ['widgetNo' => 1]) 
@include('widgets.calendar', ['widgetNo' => 2])
@include('widgets.suggestion', ['widgetNo' => 3])
@include('widgets.task', ['widgetNo' => 4])
@include('widgets.quick-search', ['widgetNo' => 5])
@include('widgets.message', ['widgetNo' => 6])
@include('widgets.find-expert', ['widgetNo' => 7])
@include('widgets.holiday', ['widgetNo' => 8])
@include('widgets.expenses', ['widgetNo' => 9])
@include('widgets.snap-pole', ['widgetNo' => 10])
@include('widgets.teams-cms', ['widgetNo' => 11])
@include('widgets.events-cms', ['widgetNo' => 12])
@include('widgets.team-cms', ['widgetNo' => 13]) 
@include('widgets.article-todo', ['widgetNo' => 14]) 
@include('widgets.article-cms', ['widgetNo' => 15]) 
@include('widgets.vacancies', ['widgetNo' => 16])
@include('widgets.yammer', ['widgetNo' => 17]) 
@include('widgets.poll-results', ['widgetNo' => 18])
```

As you can see I'm passing in an ID for each Widget.

Then on the home page, I have a big switch statement to decide which partial to render.

```
@foreach ($user->widgets as $widget) 

    @switch($widget->widget_id) 

        @case (1) 
            @include('widgets.quick-search-full-width', ['widgetNo' => 1]) 
            @break; 
        @case(2) 
            @include('widgets.calendar', ['widgetNo' => 2]) 
            @break; 
        @case (3) 
            @include('widgets.suggestion', ['widgetNo' => 3]) 
            @break; 
        @case (4) 
            @include('widgets.task', ['widgetNo' => 4])
            @break; 
        @case (5) 
            @include('widgets.quick-search', ['widgetNo' => 5]) 
            @break; 
        @case (6) 
            @include('widgets.message', ['widgetNo' => 6])
            @break; 
        @case(7) 
            @include('widgets.find-expert', ['widgetNo' => 7]) 
            @break; 
        @case (8) 
            @include('widgets.holiday', ['widgetNo' => 8]) 
            @break; 
        @case (9) 
            @include('widgets.expenses', ['widgetNo' => 9])
            @break; 
        @case (10) 
            @include('widgets.snap-pole', ['widgetNo' => 10]) 
            @break; 
        @case (11) 
            @include('widgets.teams-cms', ['widgetNo' => 11]) 
            @break; 
        @case (12)
            @include('widgets.events-cms', ['widgetNo' => 12]) 
            @break; 
        @case (13) 
            @include('widgets.team-cms', ['widgetNo' => 13]) 
            @break;  
        @case (14) 
            @include('widgets.article-todo', ['widgetNo' => 14]) 
            @break; 
        @case (15) 
            @include('widgets.article-cms', ['widgetNo' => 15]) 
            @break; 
        @case (16) 
            @include('widgets.vacancies', ['widgetNo' => 16]) 
            @break;
        @case(17) 
            @include('widgets.yammer', ['widgetNo' => 17]) 
            @break; 
        @case(18)
            @include('widgets.poll-results', ['widgetNo' => 18])
            @break
        @default
        <h3>You currently have no widgets</h3>
    @endswitch

@endforeach
```

I thought I could solve this with a simple break in the foreach loop but this did not work.

Comment: The piece I'm not seeing is where you loop over all the widgets.

Comment: I don't have a loop for widgets as widgets are just html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to add another version of the answer to take into account how you do it at the moment. Hopefully I understand how you are doing it.

Inside the main blade where you display all the widgets:

```
@php
$activeWidgets = $user->widgets->pluck('widget_id')->toArray();
@endphp

@include('widgets.quick-search-full-width', ['active' => in_array(1, $activeWidgets)]) 
@include('widgets.calendar', ['active' => in_array(2, $activeWidgets)])
@include('widgets.suggestion', ['active' => in_array(3, $activeWidgets)])
@include('widgets.task', ['active' => in_array(4, $activeWidgets)])
....
@include('widgets.poll-results', ['active' => in_array(18, $activeWidgets)])
```

Inside each specific widget where you display the buttons:

```
<!-- Displaying the buttons -->
@if ($active)
<i class="fa fa-bars "></i>
@else
<form action="{{action('WidgetController@store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="widget_id" value="{{ $widgetNo }}">

    <button type="submit" class="widget">
        <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a great solution but in an ideal world, shall I just create another table that has an ID and also has the blade name stored? Also, is it bad practise to use PHP directly within a blade?

Comment: Get it working like you have it, ie. the above, and then refactor. Regarding PHP inside blade, I would not say view specific php is bad, after all blade has a @php directive. You could pass the ```$activeWidgets``` in from the controller. I agree with you, in an ideal world it would be if your widget definition came from a table. But it would not change the solution, just that you do the ```@include``` from a loop.

Comment: This has been an interesting but perplexing one, as the Widgets aren't themselves intelligent, so you have to tell the application when to use what. Your proposed solution was bang on the money, it seems I was drastically over engineering.

Comment: FWIW the design and functionality seems great. Nothing wrong with the way you are encapsulating the behaviour of each widget in its own partial.

Comment: If I end up refactoring I will post the updated solution, I genuinely thought there would be a super intelligent way to do this, but I suppose in whatever scenario, as long as the logic knows which widget is which, it's probably okay.